# Using Markdown In Comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I am unable to use markdown in comments.  For example, I'm just trying to block out a snippet of code:

I tried:

- 4 Spaces at the begging of each line.
- one tab at the beginning of each line.
- pre and code tagging <>
- copying and pasting with tabs/space from gedit

None work.  How can I improve the quality of my comments by using markdown?

Answer (score 4):

There's a "help" link under the "Add Comment" button that explains more about comment markdown:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: `[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work. [Learn more](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)…

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks:

```
`but only in comments, of course`
```

You can use backticks in normal `text flow` as well.

```
You can use backticks in normal `text flow` as well.
```